# Anaconda error while installing a virtual environment

Tags: anaconda, virtualenv

I need help with this. Trying install a virtual environment to run a windows.yml file for a course i am doing. But everytime i try to run **"conda env create -f virtual_platform_windows.yml"** i get that error.

Can anyone assist in solving this problem?

ResolvePackageNotFound:

- jsonschema==2.6.0=py35_0
- path.py==10.3.1=py35_0
- alabaster==0.7.10=py35_0
- babel==2.5.0=py35_0
- vs2015_runtime==14.0.25420=0
- mkl==2017.0.3=0
- sphinxcontrib==1.0=py35_0
- qt==5.6.2=vc14_6
- nbconvert==5.2.1=py35_0
- pylint==1.7.2=py35_0
- rope==0.9.4=py35_1
- requests==2.14.2=py35_0
- vc==14=0
- isort==4.2.15=py35_0
- jedi==0.10.2=py35_2
- libpng==1.6.30=vc14_1
- icu==57.1=vc14_0
- simplegeneric==0.8.1=py35_1
- setuptools==36.4.0=py35_1
- jpeg==9b=vc14_0
- entrypoints==0.2.3=py35_0
- numpy==1.13.1=py35_0
- pytorch==0.1.12=py35_0.1.12cu80

I tried a few google searches that provided some possible solutions but i did not work